# failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies) problem with networkmanager

Tags: upgrade, error-handling

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                 130.1 KiB   102 KiB/s 00:01 [###############################################] 100%
 extra                                                  8.2 MiB  2.45 MiB/s 00:03 [###############################################] 100%
 community                                             45.0   B   200   B/s 00:00 [###############################################] 100%
 multilib                                             141.0 KiB   557 KiB/s 00:00 [###############################################] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing networkmanager-qt5 (5.111.0-1) breaks dependency 'networkmanager-qt' required by libtdesktopenvironment
```

i can't update my arch linux.what can i do to resolve this error

Comment: `libtdesktopenvironment` afaics is an AUR package. You'll have to remove that (and possibly other AUR packages that depend on it) and only then retry to update the system.

Comment: The AUR package `libtdesktopenvironment` dropped its `networkmanager-qt` dependency [4 months ago](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/commit/?h=libtdesktopenvironment&id=e2fec694ea854437909fcf8ab38715a0958d8147). Update or remove it.

Answer (score -1):

It would look like arch has broken its own dependencies. Forcing installations that ignore these seem unwise, so you would need to fix their packaging yourself instead. Or wait until someone upstream notices and fixes it. This usually happens fast.

(Herein lies a problem: "usually (fixing) happens fast" is not nice for a problem that shouldn't happen and that I've only ever seen happen to normal users doing normal user things on arch. Far from the only rolling release distro I've used, only the arch family has confronted me with these challenges. I guess it's a nice operating system if you can live with that, unreliable key rollovers when not used for a month and a couple other unrelated griefs I had, but it's not really for me. And that is fine.)

Comment: It's not Arch Linux's fault if you fail to take care of the packages you installed from an unsupported user repository (AUR).

Comment: @Devon I beg to differ. This is an ecosystemic problem with Arch, by design. Other distros don't act as if their AUR-equivalents are as useful as the Arch community does perceive and communicate them.

Comment: @Devon and while the above digs deep into the land of "Marcus has opinions on Arch", the fact that you get this conflict in an pacman update run, although the AUR updated months ago is **really** proof of the arch-shipped and advertised tools are not as user-safe as they should be. Either you support third party software sources in your distro, or you admit that AURs are a terrible idea and nobody should use them for production. Saying "here's this cool distros where it's very easy to offer an AUR", and then forbid integration of AUR managers is just insane.